# jQuery multidimensional array and scope

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, scope

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array that I could access anywhere in my script but I always get a "typeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating "arr_l[indx_td][indx_tr]".

Here is my simplified code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    arr_l = new Array();
    var indx_td;
    var indx_tr;
    arr_l[indx_td][indx_tr]=new Array();
    var width1;
    var width2;

    $("table td").each(function()
    {
        indx_td= $(this).index();
        indx_tr= $(this).parent().index();

        var element = $(this)
                      .clone()
                      .css({'display': 'inline', 'width': 'auto', 'visibility' : 'hidden'})
                      .appendTo('body');

        var rect1 = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        width1 = rect1.right - rect1.left;

        var rect2 = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        width2 = rect2.right - rect2.left;      

        element.remove();

        if(! arr_l[indx_td][indx_tr]['width1'])
        {
            arr_l[indx_td][indx_tr]['width1']=0;
            arr_l[indx_td][indx_tr]['width2']=0;
        }       
        arr_l[indx_td][indx_tr]['width1']=width1;
        arr_l[indx_td][indx_tr]['width2']=width2;
    }
})
```

All I want is this array to work and to be accessible anywhere in the script. Obviously, I don't declare the array as I should but I don't see how I could solve this.

I didn't create a jsfiddle because there is nothing to display.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: move **arr_l = new Array();** before dom ready

Comment: Your answer helped me (still got errors afterwards but it led me to the right direction), thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the parts of your 2d array before trying to access them.  For example:

```
arr_l = new Array()
// ...
// before trying to access the 2nd dimension, make sure it exists:
if (!(arr_l[index_td]) {
  arr_l[index_td] = new Array();
}
// and so on:
if (!(arr_l[index_td][index_tr]) {
  arr_l[index_td][index_tr] = {width: 0, height: 0}
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much.
I didn't know I had to check the existence of each and every dimension of the same array.